# Android HTTPS file Upload using service - (covert from HTTP to HTTPS )

Tags: java, android, https, multipartform-data

I have created an application to upload images to server using Http multi-part form data. It works fine. But i want to change this to **HTTPS** multipart formdata post to put it in my live server.

I tried changing the url to HTTPS, it didnt give me any errors but its not uploading the files.

some one help me to convert my code to support HTTPS multipart formdata post.

**Java code**

```
 /************************************ Image Selecting ******************************************/

    //method to show file chooser
    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
               // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                uploadMultipart();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //method to get the file path from uri
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();
        try {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            cursor.close();
            return path;
            // get data from cursor
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // exception handling
        } finally {
            if(cursor != null){
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void uploadMultipart() {
        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(filePath);
        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name", "sathya") //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    //Requesting permission
    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return;
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
        }
        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }


    //This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

            //If permission is granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Displaying a toast
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**********************************************************************************************/
```

**Gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MY PACKAGE NAME"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude '...'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'br.com.liveo:navigationdrawer-material:2.5.1'
    compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.1.jar')
    compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
}
```

**Updated SSL**

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                Log.d("TRUST", "authType: " + authType);

                if (authType == null || authType.length() == 0) {
                    Log.d("TRUST", "no authtype present");
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("authType");
                }

                if (chain == null || chain.length == 0) {
                    Log.d("TRUST", "no certs in chain");
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("chain");
                }

                Log.d("TRUST", "chainLength: " + chain.length);

                try {
                    chain[0].checkValidity();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new CertificateException("Certificate not valid or trusted.");
                }
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

**get client**

```
public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            MySSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There should be some `info` or `debug` messages in the logs. It should have print something. changing from http to https should not have a problem if you are using a respected network lib

Comment: Do you have SSL certificate validated from both the side?

Comment: @tnx. Yes i have a SSL certificate. I have updated the question, please have a look.